# Under Phishing attack trying to redirect forward masked domain and sub-directories via .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Hi this is what I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maskdomain\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.maskdomain\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/google\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Works but I need wildcard to also redirect directories

exam: need maskdomain.net/mysub/ redirected to google.com

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maskdomain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://google.com [R=301,L]
```

Using this method also reduces the need for the extra `RewriteCond` as it condenses it into one.

This will take a URL like - `http://maskdomain.net/anything` and redirect it to `https://google.com`.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Don't look now, but there's a huge line forming to sing your praises!

Thanks Joe!

RC

Comment: Haha, you're welcome Raymond :) I'm glad I could help you.